# Global variables not receiving data from computed variables hence data can't be displayed on html doc using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-requests

***here is what I have in my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
global_msp = 0
global_mspSales = 0
global_ago = 0
global_agoSales = 0


class Stock(models.Model):
    global global_msp
    global global_ago
    msp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    msp2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ago = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Stock{}'.format(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Opening Stock'

    def Total(self):
        x = self.msp
        y = self.msp2
        ans = x + y

        return ans

    total = property(Total)
    global_msp = total
    global_ago = ago


class Sales(models.Model):
    global global_mspSales
    global global_agoSales
    msp_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # msp sales value put by user
    ago_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # ago sales value put by user
    total_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # to be automatically computed
    msp_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # msp price value put by user
    ago_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # ago price value put by user
    msp_mult_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # to be automatically computed
    ago_mult_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # to be automatically computed
    total_mult_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # to be automatically computed

    def __str__(self):
        return 'sales {}'.format(self.id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sales Unit & Cash'

    global_mspSales = msp_sales
    global_agoSales = ago_sales

    def salesTotal(self):
        x = self.msp_sales + self.ago_sales
        return x

    total_sales = property(salesTotal)

    def mspPriceMultiplied(self):
        x = self.msp_sales * self.msp_price
        return x

    msp_mult_price = property(mspPriceMultiplied)

    def agoPriceMultiplied(self):
        x = self.ago_sales * self.ago_price
        return x

    ago_mult_price = property(agoPriceMultiplied)

    def totalMultPrice(self):
        x = self.msp_mult_price + self.ago_mult_price
        return x

    total_mult_price = property(totalMultPrice)


class Theory(models.Model):
    global global_msp
    global global_mspSales
    global global_ago
    global global_agoSales

    theory_msp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    theory_ago = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def theoryMsp(self):
        theory_msp = global_msp - global_mspSales
        return theory_msp

    theory_msp = property(theoryMsp)

    def theoryAgo(self):
        theory_ago = global_ago - global_agoSales
        return theory_ago

    theory_ago = property(theoryAgo)
```

***Here is what i have in my views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Stock
from .models import Sales
from . models import Theory


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    date = Stock.objects.all()

    context = {'date': date}
    return render(request, 'Strt/index.html', context)


def create(request):
    return render(request, 'Strt/create.html')


def view(request):
    openstock = Stock.objects.all()
    salesCash = Sales.objects.all()
    theoryStock = Theory.objects.all()

    context = {'openstocks': openstock, 'salesCashs': salesCash, 'theorystocks': theoryStock}
    return render(request, 'Strt/view.html', context)
```

***Here is what i have on view.html***

```
    {% for theoretical in theorystocks %}
    <table class="GeneratedTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">THEORETICAL CLOSING STOCK</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>MSP</td>
          <td>{{theoretical.theory_msp}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AGO</td>
          <td>{{theoretical.theory_ago}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   {% endfor %}
```

***Please note there is no error being displayed on the terminal and everything on the site works well except no data for the particular table (.html) is being displayed. please assist though i suspect its because the global variables don't hold/change value when called to do so.***

Comment: global variables are almost never the right way to go, specially not in database applications. Have you tried another strategy without globals?

Comment: Also, the line `total = property(Total)` seems to be overwriting the `IntegerField` you defined previously in the model `Stock`

Comment: No i haven't though what i want to achieve is to use values of four variable from another class into another another class. Please help im not sure how to go about that

Comment: yes im overwriting it because its computed by taking msp+msp2. The answer for this is then passed to total

Comment: When do you want to use data from one model in the other model? An application start, in a specific view? You need to consider how django works an plug your code into the right part.

Comment: You should not overwrite a model field (which is a database field), because then the model cannot access the database field to store or read data of that field

Comment: Kindly suggest how i go about fix what you advise

Answer (score 0):

You should read carefully the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/) regarding [Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/), [Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/), [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I assume that you need some classmethods on your models, which calculate the totals, based on queries with aggregate functions and than you want to call those methods in your Theory model